# Binding with a ternary between parent/child views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

Consider this code in which I'm trying to continuously animate a set of circles from red to blue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var colorOn = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { n in
            CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n%2 == 0 ? $colorOn : !$colorOn)
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    colorOn.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var size: CGFloat
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(isOn ? .red : .blue)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: isOn)
            
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is that I need them to alternate colors, as in every other circle should be red while the ones in between are blue. But I can't get the syntax right on the @Bindable property:

`Cannot convert value '$colorOn' of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected type 'Bool', use wrapped value instead`

Comment: `@State` should aways be `private`

Comment: Also its just `@Binding var isOn: Bool` the value will come from the parent `State`

Comment: Updated the question with something more interesting since I was getting downvotes.

Comment: Leave only $colorOn you can’t have a ternary there. Binding is a two way connection. You are connecting the State with the child views. It’s probably getting downvoted for lack of research this is the most basic part of SwiftUI

Comment: If you mean "can't have a ternary there", how could I have them alternating between on and off?

Comment: You probably just need a “let” based on the additional info, you don’t need a two way connection because the child isn’t writing.

Comment: Binding is just like a conduit it doesn’t have a value of its own, State is a source of truth.

Comment: The real question is **why are you passing a `Binding` to `CircleView`?** `CircleView` doesn't need a `Binding` because it does not mutate `isOn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@Binding` property means that the value actually comes from somewhere else and can be shared with other places. It create a two way binding between the view (CircleView), and the stored data (in this case is     `@State var colorOn` in `ContentView`).

It was correct if inside `CircleView`, you also had an action that could modify `isOn` such as:

```swift
struct CircleView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                ...
                .onTapGeture {
                    //Stop animation immediately
                    //It will impact to `colorOn` in `ContentView`
                    isOn = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, your purpose is to swap colors every single second, depending on the timer. So, you have nothing to do with @Binding since the CircleView is used only for displaying data. You just need to define a `Bool` that represents its on/off states.

```swift
struct CircleView: View {
    var size: CGFloat
    var isOn: Bool //<- Remove binding here

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(isOn ? .red : .blue)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5), value: isOn)
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to remove Binding ($) from ContentView then you're good to go.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorOn = false
    var body: some View {
        ...
        CircleView(size: 30, isOn: n % 2 == 0 ? colorOn : !colorOn)
        ...
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: `let isOn` not `var`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I tried in the first place and for some reason it wasn't working, but it is now.

Comment: No problem mate. @malhal yeah, but until now I don't recognize any difference between let and var in these cased. Because it's struct and can't be modified.